# How do you make an iframe appear when you click a button

Tags: javascript, html, button, iframe

```
<center>
 <button type= "button" onclick="myFunction()">Things To Do in Miami</button>
<div id="loadiframehere"> 
<iframe id="myframe"src="https://thingstodo.expedia.com/miami-florida-activities/" width="450" height="275" > </iframe>
</div>
</button>
<script>
 function myfunction(){
 var x = document.createElement("IFRAME")
 set.attribute("src","http://www.miamigov.com/home/");
set.attribute("width","600")
set.attribute("height","400")

 document.getElementByID("myframe").src="http://www.miamigov.com/home/"
document.getElementByID("myframe").width="300";
document.getElementByID("LOADHERE").appendchild(x);

}
  </script>
 </center>
</section>
```

This was the code my teacher gave us to copy but I did and the button isn't working. iframe only appears beside it before I click the button.

Comment: the set.attribute part doesnt make any sense. I think you ment x.setAttribute("src","http://www.miamigov.com/home/"); And there is no "LOADHERE" id. It is probably "loadiframehere"

Comment: You have done nothing to hide it in the first place. Can't make something appear when it is already visible

Comment: I fixed that but it still isn't working. But, thanks.

Comment: How can I hide it?

Comment: you could use the hide() and show() method take a look: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp

Comment: you need to do some basic web searching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the fix. Your code was completely wrong. You have to be aware of that Javascript is Case sensitive. getElementByID is different than getElementById.

also, you created a "x" element to be an iframe, but you also created an iframe in the html and your "set" attributes were not attached to any element. You created a function called "myFunction", but on the buttong you were calling "myfunction". Again, javascript is **Case Sensitive**.

You should study Javascript syntax.

```js
function myfunction(){
var x = document.createElement("IFRAME");
x.setAttribute("src","http://www.miamigov.com/home/");
x.setAttribute("width","600");
x.setAttribute("height","400");

document.getElementById("loadiframehere").appendChild(x);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<center>
 <button type= "button" onclick="myfunction()">Things To Do in Miami</button>
<div id="loadiframehere"> 

</div>
</center>
```

Comment: Thank you soo much !! It worked! I've been trying to figure this out for like 3 days! And thanks for the advice. You just saved my passing grade!

Comment: @Leslievramirez It's a good idea to mark Stormhashe's answer as "accepted" if it solved your problem. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer